# Error using alias declaration

Tags: c++, alias

I'm trying to compile an easy program that use the alias declaration.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using in = int;

in main ()

 {

   in a = 1;

   cout << a << '\n';

   return 0;

 }
```

The command I use to compile is `g++ -std=c++0x program_name.cxx`, using the built-in terminal in Kate on Ubuntu OS.
But it doesn't work! Any suggestion?
(instead using `typedef int in;` it works).

Comment: I am just asking for you to try it at the Ubuntu terminal and see if you get the same error. Which version of g++ are you using? It works for me with g++ 4.8.2.  check using "g++ --version"

Comment: I would try and upgrade to the newer compiler as "g++ -std=c++0x alias.cpp" works on 4.8.2 with that code

Comment: I'll try to upgrade, a sec.

Answer (score 4):

Compile in C++11 mode. [Type aliasing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) is supported only in C++11. I suspect the `g++` version that use is older and doesn't fully support c++11, hence fails with `c++0x`.

Compile with: `g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp`

and [it works.](http://ideone.com/44oL2o)

By the way, it seems to be a terrible idea to alias `int` in such a way.

Comment: @Blue Moon Sorry, it's just an example to see if alias declaration works... If I use -std=c++11 it says unrecognizes command line option.

Comment: That indicates your g++ is older. You may want to upgrade it if you want to use c++11 features.

Comment: @Blue Moon Okay, thanks! I used the command apt-get update as su. I hope it works